# How to save the data from double array to excel with EPPlus?

Tags: c#, epplus

I've spend already many hours looking for the solution and after all what I've tried having failed, I think it's time to ask the question.

I have a c# code where I store the data in a jagged array initialised as:

```
double[][] sample = new double[5][]
```

subsequently all these 5 arrays have assigned 1D arrays (vectors) of data. For the sake of demo let's say that (in reality these are quite longs data vectors):

```
sample[1] = new double[] { 1.2, 2, 3 };
sample[2] = new double[] { 0, 2, 3.2, 4 };
sample[3] = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 0.5, 111};
sample[4] = new double[] { 1, 2.2 };
sample[5] = new double[] { 1, 2, 3.1, 0.22 };
```

Now I want to save these arrays in different columns of an excel file using EPPlus. I've tired different options that I've found in here but none of these worked for me (probably I was doing something wrong).
Out of many trials, one was with use of LoadFromCollections like this:

```
worksheet.Cells[3,1].LoadFromCollections(sample[1]);
worksheet.Cells[3,2].LoadFromCollections(sample[2]);
```

etc...

which looks so simple, but this returns "Index was outside the bounds of the array." error.

I would be really grateful if someone could give me a guidance how can I get values from double[] array saved in columns of an excel file with EPPlus. I'm not very experienced coder so example of the code would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Iterate the jagged array: `for (int row = 0; row < sample.Length; row++) for (int col = 0; col < sample[row].Length; col++) worksheet.Cells[row+1,col+1].Value = sample[row][col];` There's the `row+1` and `col+1` because (IIRC) EPPlus cells start at 1 whereas the jagged arrays start at 0. EDIT: This might end up outputting them transposed from what you expect, if so, just flip the row/column usage.

Comment: Can you iterate over your array? If you can, just call `worksheet.Cells[i,j]` with those two indices.

Comment: Hi Guys!, thank you both for your comments and especially Chris for such a fast and detailed answer! Yes this works! Thank you!!! I was so fixated on the fact that it "must" be possible to do it with some one-line code to simply drop the whole array into a column of a spreadsheet, that I didn't even try the 'for' loop. This is fast-enough and neat-enough and I'm satisfied for the need of the current code. If there are non-loop methods of doing the same I'm always interested to learn about it :)

Comment: @atompol: Almost certainly the loop will always exist. There do seem to be some built-in methods with EPPlus (like you found, but I don't know how to use them), the underlying code will use the loops _somewhere_. If you like, you can create your own utility method (or extension method) to do this double-loop-output for you if you find yourself having to output collections to Excel often. EDIT: In terms of speed, it won't really matter. The differences between most methods at this scale of data will probably be inconsequential. Just use whatever is the most maintainable/easy for your code.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is possible to use EPPLus LoadFromDataTable method either. This method very useful when are one array of identical size double arrays and columns into which data must be written are side by side, but it can be used for jagged arrays either.

Initially double array must be converted to data table, this method can be in separate static class -

```
static class OperationsWithCollections
{
    internal static DataTable ConvertDoubleArrayToDataTable(double[] inputDoubleArray)
    {
        // New table.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double");
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        List<double[]> listOfDoubleArrays = new List<double[]>();
        foreach (double item in inputDoubleArray)
        {
            double[] oneElementDoubleArray = new double[1];
            oneElementDoubleArray[0] = item;
            listOfDoubleArrays.Add(oneElementDoubleArray);
        }


        // Add rows.
        foreach (var doubleArray in listOfDoubleArrays)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();

            row.ItemArray = doubleArray.Select(d => (object)d).ToArray(); //cast double array (double[]) to object array (object [])
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return table;
    }
}
```

then this data table can be written in required column, as example in B column from 2 row (if in the first this column row is header)

```
worksheet.Cells["B2"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, false);
```